# How to use SQL to update a field to next working day with an existing Holiday table in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

(DB2) take today for example (2020-04-30), 2020-05-01 is national holiday in my country and 2020-05-02, 2020-05-03 are weekends, so the the next working day of today is 2020-05-04.

All of these three days (2020-05-01, 2020-05-02, 2020-05-03) are recorded in table "Holiday". I just want to update the value of another table to the next working day. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Sample adta and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
with 
d as (select h, h + 1 day as next_day from holiday where h >= '2020-04-30')
select min(next_day) from d where next_day not in (select h from d);
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3b90c995fd9d6464d3e8c766cd38ba47).

**EDIT to update**

To perform an `UPDATE` on another table you can do:

```
update a
set d = (
  select min(next_day) from (
    select h, h + 1 day as next_day from holiday where h >= '2020-04-30'
  ) x where next_day not in (select h from holiday where h >= '2020-04-30')
)
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b220ad22b42983555a3c3fe72aa644a4).

Comment: I have tried something like this earlier today. it's working while selecting but not working for update. could you please give an example to update filed date1 in table1 like 

update table1 set date1 = nextWorkingDy where xxx=xxx

Comment: it works!! thanks a lot. may I ask one more question.. what does the 'x' mean in the clause 'x where next_day not in (select h from holiday where h >= '2020-04-30')'?

Comment: @vChen The `x` is the "table expression alias". In this case the outer SELECT is not directly selecting from a table but from a subquery (another SELECT). That subquery acts as a table and that's why it's called "table expression"; the syntax requires such table expression to have an alias. It could come in handy if you joined it with other tables/subqueries, though it's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to identify the initial sequence of adjacent holidays.  You can do this by enumerating the holidays and comparing the enumeration to the number of days in the future.  If there are none, just use hte next day:

```
select coalesce(min(hdate), :date + 1 day
from (select h.*,
             row_number() over (order by hdate) as seqnum,
             days(hdate) - days(:date) as num_days
      from holidays h
      where hdate >= :date + 1 day
     ) h
where seqnum = num_days;
```

This can be incorporated into another query using a correlated subquery, for instance.

You have gone through the trouble of creating a `holidays` table.  You might as well go the next step and create a full calendar table, with a "holiday" flag.  Then this logic would be simpler and could be directly in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for any given date must be as follows:

-- The next day, if it's not a holiday.
-- The first "gap" in holidays after this given date otherwise.

```
UPDATE TARGET
SET DT =
COALESCE
(
(SELECT V.DT FROM (VALUES DATE('2020-04-29') + 1) V(DT) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HOLIDAY A WHERE A.DT = V.DT))
,
(SELECT MIN(DT + 1) FROM HOLIDAY A WHERE A.DT > DATE('2020-04-29') AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HOLIDAY B WHERE B.DT = A.DT + 1))
);
```